# Can’t access object key inside object function?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I am building a web app text based RPG game. The game will use textNodes and move to the next “question” after each answer is chosen from a question.

In my game, I will allow the user to select perks at the start of the game.

One of these perks is “greaser”.

There are factions in this game, and I want to check if the player has a greaser perk and also check to see if that question that is currently being asked contains the faction “greaser”.

If both of these things are true, I will run the same logic, but with reduced damage. If not, I’ll just run the function as it appears.

Here is the code for 2 questions, one of which has a function.

```
function addRadiatedStatus() {
  character.radiated = true;
}

const textNodes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "Do you want to help this person?",
    options: [
      {
        text: "Yes",
        nextText: 2,
      },
      {
        text: "No",
        nextText: 2,
      },
    ],
    faction: "Greaser",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "It was a trap, do you run or kill them?",
    options: [
      {
        text: "Run",
        nextText: 3,
        damage: 0,
      },
      {
        text: "Kill",
        nextText: 5,
        damage: 8,
        moneyDrop: 20,
        radiationDamage: 2,
        function: function update() {
          if (character.greaser == true && textNodes[1].faction == "greaser") {
            console.log("greaser check worked");
          }
          console.log("upadte function worked");
          character.health -= this.damage;
          character.cash += this.moneyDrop;
          character.radiationLevel += this.radiationDamage;
          character.maxHP -= this.radiationDamage;
          if (this.radiationDamage >= 1) {
            addRadiatedStatus();
          }
          console.log("character HP" + " " + character.health);
          console.log("character maxHP" + " " + character.maxHP);
          console.log("moneyDrop " + " " + this.moneyDrop);
          console.log("character cash" + " " + character.cash);
          console.log("radiation level" + " " + character.radiationLevel);
          console.log("character Raditated?" + " " + character.radiated);
        },
      },
    ],
    faction: "Greaser",
  },
];

textNodes[1].options[1].function();
```

As you can see, I am hard coding `textNodes[1].faction`, which will become very annoying once I have hundreds of questions/choices.

I am looking for a way to say something like `textNodes[textNodes.id].faction’, allowing me t reuse code and no have to hard code.

I am also confused on how I can also automatically call any function within a question choice/answer , because currently, I am hard coding the fucntion call at the bottom of my page like this `textNodes[1].options[1].function()`.

I want to be able todo 2 things...

1. Call that function automatically whenever the choice is chosen by the player
2. Dynamically add the textNode ID to the if/else check for “greaser”.

I am new to javascript and I am not sure why I am having trouble obtaining the Key “id” from within my function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: okay just to simplify, you having trouble pulling that function from options right? what error is it displaying?

Comment: okay so first thing that is a red flag for me; whenever you have an object in an array its best to define a type for that object, trying to fetch a property that might not exist in one of those objects is going to give you headaches like this

Comment: @D1ZZYD23 no the issue I am having refers to this if / else ... `if(character.greaser == true && textNodes[1].faction == 
            "greaser"){
                console.log("greaser check worked");
            }` , the issue is, I have to hard code `textNodes[1].faction`, but I want to dynamically add the ID of the question so that I do not have to hard code it. I tried a few things like `textNodes[this.id].faction`, but can’t seem to get anything to work.

Comment: @D1ZZYD23 the other issue is that right now, I am hard coding the function call, but I would rather the function automatically run ( and only run ), if that text node is chosen in the game. The whole point is that each question option will have a function attached to it, and choosing that function in game should automatically call that function. I am not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: @ETHan take a look at my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your callback function declaration. You are using:

```
function: function update(){
```

and to call it you use:

```
textNodes[1].options[1].function();
```

Instead you could write it like this:

```
update: () => {
```

and call it like this:

```
textNodes[1].options[1].update();
```

Additionally if you don't want to hard code anything you could change the character object and instead of boolean `character`.`greaser` you could create string `character`.`faction` having value `greaser`, then you could simply do this

```
if (character.faction == this.faction) {
      console.log("greaser check worked");
}
```

You could also try to pass the `id` as an argument of the `update()` function.

```
update: (id) => { // pass id in update function

if (character.faction == textNodes[id].faction) { // check is done
      console.log("greaser check worked");
}

textNodes[1].options[1].update(1); //  this could help in case you want to also check values of other textNodes
```

Comment: Okay I will try this and see how/If this works... but I still have the issue of calling the function. I’d o not want to hard code the function call, because I the function should only be called if that “choice”/text node option is chosen. Is there a way to have the function run automatically once the object is called?

Comment: @ETHan check the update perhaps passing the `id` in `update()` function arguments serves you better.

Answer (score 0):

Add another function to find the desired textNode. Then call the function for that textNode as

```
function findTextNode(){
   if(character.greaser == true){
   var textNode=textNodes.filter(textNode => textNode.faction === "Greaser") 
   if(textNode){ 
     return textNode
   }
   return null;
}
var textNode=findTextNode();
if(textNode && textNode.update){// if textNode not null and have update function 
  textNode.update();
}

//Then update function will be as

update: function update(){
... function body goes here ...
   }
```